# clearing the value of time jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this loop

im using time interval for every 3seconds

```
 $(window).blur(function () {
            clearInterval(time);
            time = setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("CheckExpiration", "admin")",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == 1)
                        {
                            window.location.href="/admin"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
        $(window).focus(function () {
            time = setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("RefreshCookies", "admin")",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == 1) {
                            alert(Expired);
                        }
                   }
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
```

but every time i blur the page it seems that it has a conflict they both firing instead one i think i clear the time in the blur event.. currently doing a login for my application and i want to check if the cookie has expired when the window is inactive and it will automatically promt to log in when the cookie is expired.. can anyone help me out?
i think the solution for this is to clear the value of TIME how to do it?

Comment: Where are you declaring 'time'? Is it somewhere outside of these two methods?

Comment: I think you should use two different time handler for both the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you use the `setInterval` to called ajax. Is means even the interval is stop not means the ajax will stop too, cause it's work asynchronously. that why is not firing one when you blur the page.

to fix it we need a flag to prevent the `success` function in ajax called doing when you blur or focus the page. for more it will be great if you should called ajax again after the last one is completed for decrease server load. so we use `loop` and `setTimeout` recursive technique.

for fixed see code below

```
   // flag when is blur
   var isBlur = false;

   $(window).blur(function () {

        isBlur = true; // flaged

        (function loop() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("CheckExpiration", "admin")",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 1 && isBlur)
                    {
                        window.location.href="/admin"

                        // this make sure u call it when the ajax is complete
                        setTimeout(loop, 3000); 
                    }
                }
            });
        })();
    });

    $(window).focus(function () {

        isBlur = false; // flaged

        (function loop() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("RefreshCookies", "admin")",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 1 && !isBlur) {
                        alert(Expired);

                        // this make sure u call it when the ajax is complete
                        setTimeout(loop, 3000); 
                    }
               }
            });
        })();
    });
```

Hope this help!